# AWS EC2 instances are "Out of Service" after getting registered with ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am facing a problem in AWS. I am creating and registering an instance with an ELB. Though it is getting registered, it is not passing through the health check and showing Out-of-Service. The error reason is "*Instance has failed at least the Unhealthy Threshold number of health checks consecutively*".

My health check values are as follows:

```
Ping Target: TCP:80
Timeout: 10 seconds
Interval: 24 seconds
Unhealthy Threshold: 6
Healthy Threshold: 10
```

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Chandan

Comment: I got same issue would you please share the solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is your instance behind the ELB running a web server ? If it is does it return an '200' (OK) ? If not then that's your problem.

If you are running a web service that returns a 200, is your security group open to the ELB? Meaning the ELB's source security group has to allowed into your instance's security group.

Comment: Hi, I have created an instance and an ELB through AWS console. Right now the instance does not have any web server. Besides that, I have opened all TCP, UDP & ICMP ports for instance's security group.

Comment: In order for the ELB to be 'in service', the instance needs to running a web server or something that is servicing port 80.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you application is running and not throwing any exception. In my case, it was node application
1. right click on 'EC2 > Load Balancer > ' and select on 'Edit health check'
2. change the protocol from https to tcp
3. Click on instance tab and status was inService

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked (became in-service), by changing the port from 80 (default) to 8080, where we installed Tomcat web server.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ping target of tcp port from 80 to 8080 for 20 seconds(depending on your timeout) and back to port 80 worked for me.

1. right click on 'EC2 > Load Balancer > ' and select on 'Edit health check'
2. change 'Ping Port' to 8080 and 'Save'
3. Wait 20 seconds and change the port back to 80 and 'Save'
4. click on the 'Instance' tab and the 'Status' should as 'InService'